# Collapsing margin alignment in Firefox

Tags: html, css

TLDR: [this codepen](http://codepen.io/jackocnr/pen/eDLgr) works fine in Chrome, but the alignment is off in Firefox.

I'm building a [jQuery plugin](https://github.com/Bluefieldscom/intl-tel-input) which modifies a text input to give it a dropdown button on the left. In order to get the positioning right, I add a wrapper div, which is the same height as the input, so the button can be absolutely positioned on top of the input, and yet still have the same height:

```
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
#overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 30px;
}
```

This works fine until the input has vertical margin: then the container grows to include the margin, and so the dropdown button grows with it. My solution to this was margin collapsing: I gave the input display:block which meant that the container ignored it's margin. All good.

```
input {
  margin: 20px 0 40px; /* testing */
  display: block;
}
```

But now the problem is that by default, inputs are inline elements e.g. you might want to have a submit button next to the input. So I wrapped the whole thing in a container div with display:inline-block, so another inline element like a button can happily sit next to it.

```
#container {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

This works fine in Chrome, but has weird alignment issues in Firefox when there's any vertical margin on the input. Below I've added the final markup. There's also a codepen link at the top.

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <input>
    <div id="overlay"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<button>Submit</button>
```

**Edit**: the point is that this is a plugin and I'm trying to work with the user's existing markup and CSS e.g. they have this markup:

```
<input><button>Submit</button>
```

and their existing CSS has vertical margin on the input, and I want them to be able to just initialise my plugin on the input and it just work, without forcing them to change their markup/CSS. Now because the plugin needs to add lots of markup around the input (for the overlay and the dropdown list), I wrap it all up in a container div. This container div is the limit of our reach (and does not include the button element, or anything else they choose to put next to their inputs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this, you'll need to define a `line-height` in your parent `div#test2`. Without it, [different browsers will give it different values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height#Values). This will cause Firefox to cause this weird result.

Now, the `line-height` isn't the only problem, also the `vertical-align`'s baseline value will generate a different result for inline elements than it is for inline-block elements that have a different height than the surrounding inline content. To fix this, change the value to `top` for the `#container` element (since that's the `inline-block` element).

The final result would have the following changed (only pasting the parts that changed):

```
#test2 {
    background-color: green;
    line-height:70px;
    #container {
        // replicate the inline nature of the input
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align:top;
    }
    //the rest of the #test2 nested code
}
```

That would look like [**this**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BAmKn).

## Reply to comment

I've made something that does work by the requirements set. Since you said the extra code (so the divs around the input) are made by the plugin itself, I've taken the liberty of changing that a bit to make this work.

The way it can work quite easily is just not using inline-blocks at all, and sticking with the inline elements. This would change the styles to the following:

```
#container {
    // replicate the inline nature of the input
    display: inline;
}
#wrapper {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
}
input {
    // you'll want to make sure the typed text doesn't appear behind the overlay
    padding-left:35px;
}
#overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 1px;
    width: 30px;
    background-color: #00C2FF;
}
```

Notes:

- I didn't bother making the overlay cover the full height of the input, since your plugin would just make it a flag anyway. To make it cover the full height, just set negative `top` and `bottom` styles on the overlay, equal to the computed padding-top and padding-bottom (resp.) on the input. In this case, you'd have to change them to `top:-5px;bottom:-5px;`. (you can get the computed style via jQuery's `$(input).css('padding-top')`)
- You could actually also remove the whole `#container` from it, since the only style it has now is `display:inline` which really doesn't add anything to the whole thing.
- I've added a padding-left to your input, because otherwise you'd have to type behind the overlay, which is just silly.

Comment: Very cool solution, but I'm sad to say it's impossible. I've updated the question to be super clear about what can and can't be changed.

Comment: @jackocnr please see my updated answer. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Wow! So simple and so effective! This is the best answer yet. The only thing stopping me awarding the bounty is that you have to know the padding on the input in order to position the overlay, but the padding is set by the user (to fit in with their existing styling). I suppose the workaround would be to hack the CSS with jQuery, but this is something I've wanted to avoid. If no-one comes up with a better answer I will give you the bounty. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Is the HTML generated by the plugin and it needs to stay exactly the same? I'm not sure I can figure out exactly why the second example is not working, but you seem to have too many div elements there. You could make since simpler:

HTML

```
<div id="test1">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <input>
    <div id="overlay"></div>
    <button>submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

SCSS

```
input, button {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}

input {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 35px;
}

#test1 {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 20px 0 40px 0;
  #wrapper {
    position: relative;
    #overlay {
      position: absolute;
      top: 1px;
      left: 1px;
      width: 30px;
      background-color: #00C2FF;
    }
  }
}
```

[Codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bIxju)

I've removed the margin, and instead used padding on the parent, it achieves the same thing. You'll also want some `padding-left` on your input field so the entered text doesn't disappear behind your overlay `div`.

EDIT: In case you are unable to change the markup:

SCSS:

```
#test2 {
  background-color: green;
  #container {
    // replicate the inline nature of the input
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px 0 40px 0;
  }
  #wrapper {
    // this is just here to be display:block and ignore the margin on the input
    display: block;
    position: relative;
  }
  input {
    // tell parent to ignore margin
    //display: block;
    margin: 0;
  }
  #overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    bottom: 1px;
    left: 1px;
    width: 30px;
    background-color: #00C2FF;
  }
}
```

[codepen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bFyjG)

Removed the `block` and `margin` declarations from the `input` field, and moved the spacing to padding of the `#container` element.

Comment: If the question was about fixing the margin issue, removing it is like cheating... But maybe you are right and margin is not needed, so it is a case of [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, but the point is I'm trying to work with user's existing markup and CSS e.g. they have <input><button>Submit</button> and their existing CSS has vertical margin on the input, and I want them to be able to just initialise my plugin and it just work, without the hassle of changing their markup/CSS

Comment: So have the over override your default css to fit their needs. No one complains about it jQuery and other plugins don't work right out the box. Solving this problem may in turn lead to another problem. That said, maybe you should edit your question to specify exactly what can and can't be changed.

Comment: @jackocnr Last attempt, but not sure if it within your requirements http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wJxDl

Comment: Thanks again, but I'm afraid not. I've edited the question to be super clear about what can and can't be changed.

Answer (score 0):

"**Disclaimer**": Let me just start by saying that I did not find exactly what is causing the problems in Firefox, but I did think of an alternative way you could do it.

The way this works in both Firefox and Chrome is just to use the exact same HTML as you used for your `#test1`, but on top of that, also using the CSS `:before` pseudo-element (instead of using the `#container` and `#wrapper`). The code I used was:

```
#test2 {
    background-color: green;
    position:relative;
    &:before {
        content:"";
        display:block;
        position:absolute;
        left:1px;
        top:1px;
        bottom:1px;
        margin:20px 0 40px 0;
        width:30px;
        background:#00C2FF;
    }
}
```

[**demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mrzej)

The way this works is to simply position the `:before` overlay on exactly the same place as the divs previously were. As you can see, I've used most of the same styles as you did, but instead, I've put them on the `:before` pseudo-class.

Comment: Thanks for this. An interesting approach, but I don't just need a coloured square for the overlay: I definitely need to use real (quite complicated) markup, which I don't think this solution allows?

Comment: @jackocnr well I wouldn't know if I don't know what markup you'd need. Could you link me to a demo of what you want it to do? I could then try to see if it would work with `:before` for you. Also, you can do [a lot more than what I did](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content#Syntax) with the `content` property of the `:before` pseudo-element.

Comment: There's a link in the question to the plugin's Github page, which includes lots more details about the plugin, including a link to a demo.

Comment: [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lfcrE) is my best try. I'm not sure about attaching event handlers to it though, and it's also not really a clickable area as much as it is 2 clickable elements. You're probably better off with [my other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21358701/1256925) if you're going to add things like that yeah.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers don't know why it doesn't work on Firefox. Well, I think that Firefox has the right behavior and it's a Chrome problem.

In short, you want to align an input with a button. But the input is inside a wrapper. Then, you can use `vertical-align` to control the vertical aligning between the wrapper and the button, but not between the input and the button.

Here you can see an screenshot with different `vertical-align`:

[image: Screenshot with different <code>vertical-align</code>]

See [the code](http://jsfiddle.net/9xe7t/).

If you want to align the input and the button (last case in the image), you have a problem, because any of the keywords you can use with `vertical-align` does that. Only in case that input's top margin and bottom margin are equal, then `vertical-align: middle` works.

But in general, you have have another solution: `vertical-align` also accepts a `<length>` value.

And, to get a perfect alignment, you should use the formula

```
vertical-align: -(input bottom margin)
```

Or, if you want to align them even if the button has a bottom margin, then

```
vertical-align: -(input bottom margin) + (button button margin)
```

---

The code formula above works with `inline-block` `<div>`, but not with `<buttons>`.

The formula must be fixed to

```
vertical-align: -(input bottom margin) -(input offsetHeight)/2 + 6
```

In your example

- (Input bottom margin) = 40px
- (Input offsetHeight) = 31px

Then, you need

```
vertical-align: -(input bottom margin) -(input offsetHeight)/2 + 6
```

[**Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BHlgD)

Comment: "Other answers don't know why it doesn't work on Firefox" - not true, see my second answer.

Comment: Thank you for this enlightening answer, but unfortunately the margin is an unknown variable set by the user. I'm sorry if that was not clear - I have edited the question to clarify this.

Comment: @jackocnr Yes, but if it's a jQuery plugin you could detect the margin with JS and set the `vertical-align` depending on it.

Comment: @Oriol Your [**Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BHlgD) link doesn't look good at all in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I could achieve it with the following.[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/iwokc)  You will have to know the css applied to input and apply it to button as well

```
  button{
   position:absolute;
   margin-left:5px;
  }
  input, button {
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 20px 0 40px 0;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

please update below in your code.

```
input, button {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    margin: 20px 0 40px;
    padding: 5px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

hope it will work

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Isycu

Comment: No - read the question - the button is outside the control of the plugin.